# Динамическое создание ListViewAdapter во фрагменте с картинкой из URL

Tags: json, url, imageview

Добрый день. Имеется JSON с данными, с помощью AsyncTask я парсю его и в цикле получаю тексты и ссылку на картинку для каждой статьи, затем я динамически добавляю в адаптер ListView Заголовок и Картинку.
Вопрос, как динамически добавить в news_item картинку и потом вставить её в свежесозданный listView? 
Вот сам код: [github.com](https://github.com/AlexRU18/JsonParserProject/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/alexsprod/jsonparserproject/fragments/CatOneFragment.java)

Спасибо всем заранее, я только учусь. С новым годом!

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String url = "http://legs-legs.ru/cat1json.php?json=cat1";
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
    newslist = new ArrayList<>();
    Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = null;
                c = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString("id");
                String title_cat1 = c.getString("title_cat1");
                String fulltext_cat1 = c.getString("fulltext_cat1");
                // tmp hash map for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> news_item = new HashMap<>();
                news_item.put("id", id);
                news_item.put("title_cat1", title_cat1);
                String imgURL_cat1 = c.getString("img_cat1");  //Получаю строку с адресом картинки
                Log.d("ImageURL is: ", imgURL_cat1);
                newslist.add(news_item);
            }
        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //Здесь мне нужно добавить картинку в адаптер
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), newslist,
            R.layout.item_cat1, new String[]{"title_cat1", "fulltext_cat1"},
            new int[]{R.id.title_cat1, R.id.fulltext_cat1});
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно Picasso решил мой вопрос, всем спасибо:

```
Picasso.with(this.getContext().getApplicationContext())
                        .load(String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getLink())))
                        .resize(250, 190)
                        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_empty)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(new Target() {
                            @Override
                            public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                                holder.imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            }
                        });
```